# requestAnimationFrame with this keyword

Tags: javascript, object, animation, this

I'm using `webkitRequestAnimationFrame` but I'm having trouble using it inside of an object. If I pass the `this` keyword it will use `window` and I can't find a way for it to use the specified object instead.

Example:

```
Display.prototype.draw = function(){
  this.cxt.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  //Animation stuff here.

  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(this.draw);
};
```

I have also tried this but to no avail:

```
Display.prototype.draw = function(){
  this.cxt.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  //Animation stuff here.

  var draw = this.draw;
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(draw);
};
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

> I'm trying to pass display.draw which is the function in which webkitRequestAnimationFram resides.

`webkitRequestAnimationFrame` will presumably call the function you pass in, something like this:

```
function webkitRequestAnimationFrame(callback)
{
    // stuff...
    callback();
    // other stuff...
}
```

At this point, you have dissociated (detached) the `draw` function from its invocation context. You need to bind the function (`draw`) to its context (the instance of `Display`).

You can use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), but this [requires JavaScript 1.8 support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) (or just use the recommended patch).

```
Display.prototype.draw = function()
{
    // snip...

    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(this.draw.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: I'm trying to pass `display.draw` which is the function in which `webkitRequestAnimationFram` resides.

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem: you can pass the function, but `webkitRequestAnimationFrame` will invoke it later, and `this` will not point to the right object because you've "detached" the function from its object. See my edit (pending).

Comment: The `bind` method works perfectly (Never knew about that, thnx :] ) but passing `this.draw();` with a closure still throws an error. `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'draw'`

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't work `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Display> has no method 'fn'` but don't worry about it, the bind method is good enough. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I did not know about the Function.bind method. My imaginary hat off to you! :)

Comment: Thank you. It's a new step in JS knowledge. BTW, do all browsers support `.bind` ?

Comment: Looks like I'm having the same problem here.  Is there no other way to do this, save creating a global variable reference to the object?  I'd prefer some trick that makes it work in all browsers.

Comment: @krb686 the `Function.bind` shim ensures browser compatibility, or you can pass an anonymous function instead of `this.draw.bind(this)`, but that's not as clean.

Comment: Which method (bind, global, closure) is the fastest / most efficient?

Comment: @MattBall :: I tried to use bind but its giving Maximum stack size exceeded error.

Answer (score 36):

Now that ES6/2015 is here, if you are using a transpiler then an arrow function has lexical `this` binding so instead of:

```
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(this.draw.bind(this));
```

you can do:

```
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(() => this.draw());
```

which is a bit cleaner.

I've used this effectively with Typescript transpiling to ES5.

Comment: This is what I now use.

Comment: I just used this technique, and I had to put an argument in the arrow function, corresponding to the timeStamp argument that the rAF() callback receives: `(t) => this.draw(t)`

Answer (score 6):

I can't guarantee that this is a good idea and that I'm right, but running .bind on every requestAnimationFrame means creating a new function on every iteration. It just doesn't sound right to me.

That's why in my project I cached the bound function to avoid the anti-pattern.

Simple example:

```
var Game = function () {
    this.counter = 0;
    this.loop = function () {
        console.log(this.counter++); 
        requestAnimationFrame(this.loop);
    }.bind(this);
    this.loop();
}
var gameOne = new Game();
```

If you have a more complex project with prototype inheritance you can still create a cached function with "this" bound in object's constructor

```
var Game = function () {
    this.counter = 0;
    this.loopBound = this.loop.bind(this);
    this.loopBound();
}
Game.prototype.loop = function () {
    console.log(this.counter++); 
    requestAnimationFrame(this.loopBound);
}
var gameOne = new Game();
```

Thoughts?
http://jsfiddle.net/3t9pboe8/ (look in the console)

Comment: I modified your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uuvqju4L/1/) to (I think) test the difference between caching the bound function and not. I was surprised to see nearly identical performance between the two (in Firefox 47, Chrome 52, and IE 11). It appears as though the function created by `bind` is cached by the browser, but I don't know what's actually going on. I even tried running each individually to avoid interference from the browser's optimization of `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: @SeanH in this case "loop" is a really simple function consisting of a counter incrementation and one condition check. I wonder if using "bind" on every iteration of much more complex function would make a bigger difference. Probably the gain of this practice on requestAnimationFrame which never goes above 60fps is marginal.

Answer (score 3):

how about this:

```
Display.prototype.draw = function(){
  this.cxt.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  //Animation stuff here.

  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame( $.proxy(function() {this.draw()}, this) );
};
```

...assuming you use jquery

Comment: How to use it without jquery?? I tried to use bind but its giving Maximum stack size exceeded error.

Answer (score 1):

you have not to use "this".
Keep it simple.

```
var game = {
      canvas:null,
      context:null,

    init:function(){
            // init canvas, context, etc
    },      

    update:function(){
        //do something
        game.render();                        
        requestAnimationFrame(game.update, game.canvas);        
    },            
};
```

Comment: Nice. I needed a method to be accessible from outside the class, so I used this idiom: `var update = this.update = function() { render(); requestAnimationFrame(update); }`

Answer (score 1):

Beside `bind` method, and arrow function solution (offered by Jamaes World's answer), Another (rather old) work around could be:

```
var self = this
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(
    function() {
        self.draw()
    }
);
```

Answer (score -2):

And also you might want to use requestAnimationFrame shim to make it work on all browsers https://github.com/kof/animation-frame