# Call Javascript Object Method with SetInterval()

Tags: javascript, object, methods, setinterval, momentjs

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zCFr5/)**.

I'm trying to create a countdown object that uses [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) (a plugin that I prefer over using Date())

```
var Countdown = function(endDate) {
    this.endMoment = moment(endDate);

    this.updateCountdown = function() {
        var currentMoment, thisDiff;

        currentMoment = moment();
        thisDiff = (this.endMoment).diff(currentMoment, "seconds");

        if (thisDiff > 0)
            console.log(thisDiff);
        else {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
            console.log("over");
        }
    }

    this.interval = setInterval(this.updateCountdown(), 1000);
}
```

I then create a instance of the countdown like so:

```
var countdown = new Countdown("January 1, 2014 00:00:00");
```

However the function only seems to run one time. Any ideas? Should I be using setTimeout() instead?

Comment: try `this.updateCountdown` in your call to `setInterval`.

Comment: that doesn't seem to reference the object (throws an error 'Cannot call method 'diff' of undefined): http://jsfiddle.net/zCFr5/2/

Comment: You need to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/zCFr5/3/

Comment: ah okay i see, create a local variable that stores this. do you want to write it as an answer so i can pick yours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either store your `this` context as a local variable like the following:

```
var Countdown = function(endDate) {
  var self = this;
  this.endMoment = moment(endDate);

  this.updateCountdown = function() {
      var currentMoment, thisDiff;

      currentMoment = moment();
      thisDiff = (self.endMoment).diff(currentMoment, "seconds");

      if (thisDiff > 0)
          console.log(thisDiff);
      else {
          clearInterval(self.interval);
          console.log("over");
      }
  }

  this.interval = setInterval(this.updateCountdown, 1000);
}
```

Or you can just use your variables directly such as:

```
var Countdown = function(endDate) {
  var endMoment = moment(endDate);

  this.updateCountdown = function() {
      var currentMoment, thisDiff;

      currentMoment = moment();
      thisDiff = (endMoment).diff(currentMoment, "seconds");

      if (thisDiff > 0)
          console.log(thisDiff);
      else {
          clearInterval(interval);
          console.log("over");
      }
  }

  var interval = setInterval(this.updateCountdown, 1000);
}
```

I prefer the second approach - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XYnPf/)

Answer (score 16):

You should pass a *reference* to function, not the result of its execution.
Also, you need some additional "magic" to call a method this way.

```
var me = this;
this.interval = setInterval(function () {
    me.updateCountdown();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Instead of saving a reference to `this`, you can use `Function.bind`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6065221/139010

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work in older browsers. And no framework for that implied in question.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work still, here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zCFr5/1/

Comment: The answer I linked addresses that: `Function.bind` is quite simple to shim.