# Failed to execute 'requestAnimationFrame' on 'Window': The callback provided as parameter 1 is not a function.

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

```
window.requestAnimFrame = function(){
return (
    window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
    function(/* function */ callback){
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    }
);
}();

function animationSequence(elem, ind) {
    this.ind = ind;
    this.elem = elem;
    this.distance = 450;
    this.duration = 900;
    this.increment = 0;
    this.start = Math.abs(this.ind)*450;
    var requestId = requestAnimFrame(this.animate);
    this.move();

    this.move = function() {
        this.elem.style.left = this.start - this.increment + "px";
    }
    this.animate = function() {
        var self = this;
        this.move();
        this.increment += 5;
        if (this.increment >= 450) { 
            if (this.ind == 0) { console.log("true"); this.elem.style.left = "1350px" }
            cancelAnimFrame(requestId);
        }
    }
    // this.animate();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to place `var requestId = requestAnimFrame(this.animate);` below the `this.animate` function definition?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ok so help me out if I'm getting you wrong - is your problem that you have lost your reference to `this` within the animate method? i.e. you can't call `this.move()` or increment the increment?

If so try this-

```
 var requestId = requestAnimFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
```

See this answer about binding with requestAnimation callbacks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065169/requestanimationframe-with-this-keyword).

And this [blog post on binding](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/23/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/).

**Update May 2019**

If you can use ES6 you can employ an arrow function, which will maintain scope like this:

```
let requestId = requestAnimFrame(() => { this.animate(); });
```

Read about arrow functions here:

[Blog post about arrow functions and the keyword this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-es6-the-dope-way-part-ii-arrow-functions-and-the-this-keyword-381ac7a32881)

Comment: @BlinkingCahill Thanks mate, it worked for me as well!

Comment: You saved my day mate. :)