# Passing class's method in requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript

When I call `app.update()` in console this works, but when I use `requestAnimationFrame` there is an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'drops' of undefined at update (oee.html:40)

It works while using `setInterval`.

What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style media="screen">
      *{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
      }
      #app{
        height:100vh;
        width:100vw;
        background-color: red;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .drop{
        position:absolute;
        background-color:#fff;
        top:10px;
        width: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      class App{
        constructor(){
          this.el = document.getElementById("app");
          this.height=this.el.clientHeight;
          this.width=this.el.clientWidth;
          this.drops=[];
          for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
            this.drops.push(new Drop(this.height,this.width));
          }
        }
        update(){
          this.drops.forEach(function(drop){
            drop.update();
          });
        }
      }

      class Drop{
        constructor(appHeight,appWidth){
          this.speed=Math.random();
          this.el=document.createElement("div");
          this.el.setAttribute("class","drop");
          this.el.style.height=(Math.random()*10+5)+"px";
          this.el.style.left=(Math.random()*appWidth)+"px";
          this.appHeight=appHeight;
          document.getElementById("app").appendChild(this.el);
          this.el.style.top=0;
        }

        update(){
          this.top=this.el.style.top.replace("px","");
          this.el.style.top=(this.top>this.appHeight)?"0px":(parseFloat(this.top) + parseFloat(this.speed*300))+"px";
        }
      }
      var app=new App();
      requestAnimationFrame(app.update);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [requestAnimationFrame with this keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065169/requestanimationframe-with-this-keyword) | `this` changes when using requestAnimationFrame, so you have to `.bind()` the function like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgVxxK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `app.update()`, you are calling the `update` function as a method of the `app` object.

But the code shown in the question doesn't call your function as a method:

```
requestAnimationFrame(app.update);
```

When you write `app.update` (without using parentheses), you are just getting a reference to the `app.update` function *as a standalone function*. It loses the connection to the `app` object. When `requestAnimationFrame()` later calls your `update` function, it just calls the function directly without any `this` object. So when `update` references `this.drops` it fails.

You didn't list your `setInterval()` version, but one thing we can be sure of is that it did *not* look like this:

```
setInterval( app.update, 10 );
```

If that were the code you used, it would have the same problem you're having with `requestAnimationFrame()`. You may have written something like this:

```
setInterval( function() {
    app.update();
}, 10 );
```

Now your `setInterval()` callback is the anonymous function, and that function calls `app.update()` *as a method*.

You can do the same thing with `requestAnimationFrame()`, except that you need to call `requestAnimationFrame()` each time you want to wait for another frame. In other words, it's more like `setTimeout()` rather than `setInterval()`. So it could look like this:

```
var updater = function() {
    app.update();
    requestAnimationFrame( updater );  // for subsequent frames
};

requestAnimationFrame( updater );  // for the first frame
```

Now your code should work as expected.

Here's an [updated version of yuriy636's CodePen test](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXxqzE) with animation working.