# Why this object become null in recursive call in es6 grammar. How to a recursive call in es6 programmer?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

A class is defined as follow:

```
export default class FishGame {
  constructor(window) {
    .......
    this.window = window
    ......
  }

  gameloop() {
    this.window.requestAnimationFrame(this.gameloop);
    var now = Date.now();
    this.deltaTime = now - this.lastTime;
    this.lastTime = now;
    ....
  }
}
```

you can see the function gameloop is a recursive call. 
I call this function in this way:

```
 function game() {
    let fishGame = new FishGame(this);
    fishGame.gameloop();
 }
```

while a exception is thrown, could someone tell me why this object is null?:
[image]

Comment: [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) isn't recursive.

Comment: Change to this: `this.window.requestAnimationFrame(this.gameloop.bind(this));`.  Passing a method to a function as a callback loses the `this` that you want to go with it so you can use `.bind()` to force it to be attached properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` is lost in the callback. There are a few clean ways of doing it described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37773297/6243352). One approach is to bind `this` to the callback, or use an arrow function which has `this` bound to it automatically:

```js
class FishGame {
  constructor() {}

  gameloop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => this.gameloop());
    console.log(Date.now());
  }
}

new FishGame().gameloop();
```

Comment: Hi ggorlen, I can't make it work by use "self". Is there any difference with "this"?

Comment: Yeah, the difference is that `this` gets lost inside the `requestAnimationFrame` context. It stops pointing to an instance of `FishGame`. What do you mean you can't make it work--can you be more specific? The code snippet works fine for me.

Comment: Hi ggorlen, it does work! thanks a a lot.  While I want to know why this gets lost in requestAnimationFrame? can we use the bind mechanism?

Comment: You can--there should be all the info you need in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065169/requestanimationframe-with-this-keyword).

Comment: There are much better ways to solve this than using a global variable.

Comment: @FelixKling agreed completely. I wanted to use a similar technique as the OP but I've updated to use best practice.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class FishGame {
  static loop(game) {
    function doloop() {
      requestAnimationFrame(doloop)
      game.gameloop()
    }
    
    doloop()
  }
  
  constructor() {
    self = this;
    this.name = "Lamax"
  }

  gameloop() {
    console.log(Date.now()+": "+this.name);
  }
}

FishGame.loop(new FishGame());
```

The problem is that you are calling this, inside the function thats passed as a argument in requestAnimationFrame, try the above snipet

Comment: although I add this, it would thrown null in the second call of gameloop. you can see it was successfully log the window object in first time.