# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '#fieldname')

Tags: javascript, typeerror, this, es6-class

I am trying to create this class `Animator` that I use to repeatedly draw on a canvas. It is simple enough.

The class is initialized with a canvas 2D context. The private method `#update` is responsible to draw things on the canvas. It will invoke itself by using `requestAnimationFrame`.

The `start` and `stop` methods are supposed to start and stop the animation by use of `requestAnimationFrame` and `cancelAnimationFrame`.

However, I am getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '#ctx')

I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong. I think it has to do something with passing `this.#update` as a callback to `requestAnimationFrame`/`cancelAnimationFrame`, but I cannot quite figure it out.

Could someone please help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```js
class Animator {
  #ctx;
  #requestId;
  
  constructor(ctx) {
    this.#ctx = ctx;
    this.#ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  }
  
  #update() {
    this.#ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 10, 10);    
    this.#requestId = requestAnimationFrame(this.#update);
  }
  
  run() {
    this.#requestId = requestAnimationFrame(this.#update);
  }
  
  pause() {
    if (this.#requestId) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(this.#requestId);
    }
    
    this.#requestId = null;
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('c');
const test = new Animator(ctx);
test.run();
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) or [requestAnimationFrame with this keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065169/requestanimationframe-with-this-keyword)

Comment: @Ivar Yes, it did. Can't imagine why I missed that question. This question needs to close.